# Insert new node at the beginning of Linked-List

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

In a simple Linked List implementation on C,  I couldn’t figure out a line of function named insert().
It takes a char and add to the linked list in alphabetical order.
The line is about creating a new node when the list is empty. And since there will be only one node on the list, the line should be like I’ve commented, am I wrong?

```
/****************************************************/

void insert( ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value ){
ListNodePtr newPtr;    
ListNodePtr previousPtr;
ListNodePtr currentPtr;

newPtr = malloc( sizeof( ListNode) );

if( newPtr != NULL ){       //is space available
    newPtr->data = value;       //place value in node
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;      //node does not link to another node

    previousPtr = NULL;
    currentPtr = *sPtr;         //indirection to startPtr

    while( currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data ){
        previousPtr = currentPtr;               //walk to ...
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;       //... next node
    }

    //insert new node at the beginning of the list
    if( previousPtr == NULL ){
        newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;            ///////////////////////////////////////////////  newPtr->nextPtr = NULL   ???
        *sPtr = newPtr;
    }
    else{           //insert new node between previousPtr and currentPtr
        previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
        newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
    }

}
else
    printf( "%c not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
}//end-of insert

/*******************************************************/
```

the typedef instructions in main() are;

```
typedef struct listNode ListNode;
typedef ListNode* ListNodePtr;
```

and the function insert() is called in main() like this;

```
insert( &startPtr, item);
```

initialization of startPointer in main();

```
ListNodePtr startPtr = NULL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot a case. The line you marked will be called if

- the list is empty
- the character is smaller than all other characters in the list and has to be inserted at the beginning of the list

To understand the second case, have a look at the code before:

```
while( currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data ){
    previousPtr = currentPtr;               //walk to ...
    currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;       //... next node
}
```

The condition `value > currentPtr->data` is true in the second case, so you will arrive at the line with `previousPtr == NULL` and `*sPtr != NULL` (containing its initial value, the pointer to the first node of the list).

In the first case, `*sPtr` is `NULL` indeed, in the second case, you would incorrectly throw away the whole list when using `NULL` and end up with only one character in the list and a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in a *sPtr to the function. If *sPtr points to a Node in a non-empty list, you will lose your reference to the list if you use NULL instead of *sPtr. If *sPtr is NULL the behavior is the same.

You are suggesting:

```
if( previousPtr == NULL ){
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        *sPtr = newPtr;
    }
```

but if *sPtr = Node1 and the list is:

```
Node1->Node2->Node3
```

if you want to insert before Node1 and you use your implementation

you will make your newPtr-> point to NULL
and then set your *sPtr = newPtr and lose your original list

the other implementation prepends your new node to the old list.