# Inserting to beginning of linked list (revisited)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, printf, insertion

I'm very new to coding in C (and therefore the silly exercise I am working on).  I tried looking at this [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214693/insert-new-node-at-the-beginning-of-linked-list) to a similar question, but it seems like my coding strategy is different, and ultimately I would like to understand what is the problem with my code.  I would greatly appreciate your input.

I have a linked list, a function that inserts a new node at the beginning of my list, a function that prints my linked list, and main function.

Unfortunately my knowledge of C is not good enough to understand why my function is not inserting at the beginning of the list. What is even more unfortunate is that this code does not crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} *Node_t;

void print_list(Node_t root) {
    while (root) {
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        root = root->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void add_to_list(Node_t *list, Node_t temp){
    // check if list is empty
    if ((*list)->next == NULL) {
        // insert first element
        (*list) = temp;
    }
    else {
        temp->next = (*list);
        (*list) = temp;
    }
}

int main () {

    int val1 = 4;
    int val2 = 8;
    int val3 = 15;

    Node_t list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    Node_t temp1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    Node_t temp2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    Node_t temp3 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    temp1->data = val1;
    temp1->next = NULL;
    temp2->data = val2;
    temp2->next = NULL; 
    temp3->data = val3;
    temp3->next = NULL; 

    //Initialize list with some values
    list->data = 0;
    list->next = NULL;

    /* add values to list */
    add_to_list(&list,temp1);
    add_to_list(&list,temp2);
    add_to_list(&list,temp3);

    print_list(list);

}
```

This code will only ever print the last node I have attempted to add to the list, therefore overwriting the previous nodes.

For example:

```
Running…
15 

Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single mistake in `add_to_list()` function:

```
if ((*list)->next == NULL) { // checks next of first is NULL not list is NULL
 // to insert at first
```

should be just:

```
if ((*list) == NULL){ // You need to check list is NULL
```

Check [working code](http://codepad.org/pv4MOhc6)

---

> Why you were getting only `15` the last node (`temp3`) value?

Because in main you creates three temp nodes and  initialized next of every node to NULL, including `list` node so in `add_to_list()` function if condition `((*list)->next == NULL)`  always evaluates true and `list` always initialized with temp node.